# How to update without changing the value of unique fields?

Tags: php, laravel

I update user data. Form of update is fill current user data. And if I don't change email validation show me error that this email already been taken. I use `Rule::unique` that resolve this problem but this not working ?

Comment: what would be passing `$customer` to the `rules` method? and what "is not working"?

Comment: @lagbox I have  customers in database. Customer have email which is unique. When I want to udpate customer, form update is fill currently data. So when I update fist name and no change email, I I shouldn't see validation error that email been taken.

Comment: right, what are you expecting `$customer` to be? that is just a non-existing Model instance (via dependency injection) ... it has a `null` id and has no relationship to anything in the request input or route parameter

Comment: @lagbox So what can I do that `$customer->id` has not null only id customer.

Comment: where is the information to be able to look up the customer in the first place? a route parameter?

Comment: @lagbox is right we need route params and how retrieve customer model

Answer (score 1):

Fix previous answer

```
class CustomerRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
     return [
       'first_name'   => 'min:3|max:20|regex:/^[a-zA-z-0-9]+$/u',
       'last_name'    => 'min:3|max:30|regex:/^[a-zA-z-0-9]+$/u',
       ['email', Rule::unique('customers')->ignore($this->customer->id)]      
     ];
}
```

Also in your controller must receive

```
public function update(CustomerRequest $request, Customer $customer)
    {
        //Code
    }
```

Comment: Take note that it will not `$this->customer->id` will not work if you are not using route-model binding. So if not you can just call the input which is `$this->customer` which is passed from the route

Comment: yes @xenooooo you are right